# Could anyone assist on showing the correct badges for (coverage) on Github

Tags: github, coveralls, codecov

Could anyone assist on showing the correct badges for (coverage) on Github. I tried coveralls and codecov and both of them are showing (unknown) eventhough the code in Travis CI is passing.

The link:
https://github.com/Allo0o2a/JavaTriangle

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that you have no test report in your code. 
You need to provide a test report that Codecov knows to render. For instance a JaCoCo report.

You can find a working project with codecov [here](https://github.com/joanb/KotlinChessClock)

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @joan, a coverage report is needed.

Also, your Codecov.yml file is not valid. You can test your YAML by posting to this end point: https://api.codecov.io/validate

Lastly, I think your CURL command should not be in your yaml, but rather in your bash uploader step: bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)